# document.body.setAttribute not working in IE-7

Tags: attributes, onload, javascript

I have added "test.js"  file in my .aspx page (in head section) .

In test.js  i added a script "document.body.setAttribute("onload", "testload()");"

which is working well in IE-8-9 ,Mozilla ,Chrome   and  loading testLoad() function .

But it is not working in IE-7 .

How can i set attribute  of  "body" from test.js file  in IE-7.

Comment: Inventive way of setting onload. I have never seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
window.onload = testload;
```

or

```
window.onload = function()
{
    //Some codes
}
```

Note that `body.onload` and `window.onload` are different. If you want to execute your event handler after all resources have been loaded, use `window.onload`.

Comment: @Shai, sure. If it works, you can mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IE7 doesn't support `obj.setAttribute('onload', doSomething);`. You can handle IE with timer.

```
var myiFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
myiFrame.setAttribute("id", "myiFrame");
myiFrame.setAttribute("src", "something.aspx");
myiFrame.setAttribute("class", "myclass");
myiFrame.setAttribute("frameBorder", "0"); //For IE
myiFrame.setAttribute("hspace", "0");
//For all:
myiFrame.setAttribute("onload", "testload();"); 
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myiFrame);
//For IE:
if (isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false) {
    setTimeout(function () { testload() }, 500);
}
```

That is it. If you also want to attach event listener on load, again IE needs its fix:

```
function testload() {
//Add event listener for click so that
//resize myiFrame in case any changes occur in size of content when user clicks
    var content = document.getElementById("myiFrame").contentWindow.document.body;
    if (content.addEventListener) { //For all
        content.addEventListener('click', function () {
            //find the height of the internal page
            var the_height = content.scrollHeight;

            //change the height of the iframe
            document.getElementById("myiFrame").height = the_height + 10;
        }, false);
    }
    else if (content.attachEvent) { //For IE
        cerceveIci.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
            //find the height of the internal page
            var the_height = cerceveIci.scrollHeight;

            //change the height of the iframe
            document.getElementById("kk-iframe").height = the_height + 10;
        });
    }
}
```